# DRY - Question about paths and urls from a string or model object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, path

I know how to get paths and urls no problem (eg. new_color_path for the Model Color) but what if I am trying to create a partial that can be used for multiple models and I still nee the "new_***_path" or one of the others?  Is it possible to generate the url from a model object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might get what you need from [polymorphic_url](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/PolymorphicRoutes/polymorphic_url).